# subdifferential of ReLU function composition with affine function

Tags: functions, derivatives, machine-learning, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be ReLU function, i.e., $f(x)=[\max(0,x_i)]_{i=1}^n$. Let also $g:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an affine function $g(x)=Ax+b$. What is the subdifferential of $f(g(x))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subdifferential of the composed function $h(x) := f(Ax+b)$ is simply $\partial h(x) = A^\top \partial f(Ax+b)$. Thus if suffices to find $\partial f(x)$.

**For one-dimensional ReLU**, $r(z) = \max(0,z)$ with $z\in\mathbb{R}$, it is straightforward to find its subdifferential (with a slight abuse of notation: a single element represents a singleton set containing that element):
$$\partial r(z) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{if } z > 0,\\
[0,1] &\mbox{if } z=0,\\
0 &\mbox{if } z < 0. 
\end{cases}$$
*Sketch of proof:* $r(z)$ is differentiable every except at $z=0$, thus $\partial r (z) = r'(z) \ \forall z \neq 0$. For $z=0$ it is easy to show that $\partial r (z) = [0,1]$ based on the definition of subgradient.

**For general $n$-dimensional ReLU** ($\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$), $f(x) = \max(0,x)$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and for *vector-valued functions* in general, there are different ways of generalizing the notion of subgradient. Once can use, for example, generalized inequalities based on convex cones (see [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjHp8T_-_jtAhXNyYUKHdPWC1gQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FNguyen_Tan8%2Fpublication%2F245794873_Convex_vector_functions_and_their_subdifferential%2Flinks%2F54b8690c0cf269d8cbf6cd44%2FConvex-vector-functions-and-their-subdifferential.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Qs3Vq9HoDToZGx7E2Nk_r) for example). Another solution is to use Clarke Jacobian (which is the Clarke subdifferential for vector-valued function). For the ReLU function, it can be shown that these two kinds of "subgradients" coincide (if one chooses the nonnegative orthant as the underlying cone in the first kind). I'll give a detailed derivation for the Clarke subdifferential because it's more common.

The Clarke subdifferential is the set of Clarke Jacobian matrices, defined as follows for a locally Lipschitz function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$:
\begin{equation}
D_CF(x) = \mathrm{co}\left\{\lim_{i\to\infty}DF(x_i): x_i\to x, x_i\not\in E\cup E_f \right\},\tag{*}
\end{equation}
where $E\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is any set of measure zero, $E_f$ is the set of points at which $F$ is not differentiable, $DF$ is the Jacobian matrix, and $\mathrm{co}$ denotes the convex hull. In other words: Take any sequence $x_i$ converging to $x$ while avoiding both $E$ and $E_f$, such that $DF(x_i)$ converges to a limit, then the convex hull of all such limits is $D_CF(x)$. Clearly, $D_CF(x)$ is a set of $m\times n$ matrices, and it is well-known that if $F$ is differentiable at $x$, then $D_CF(x) = \{DF(x)\}$.

Now let's compute $D_Cf$ for our ReLU function $f$. It is easy to see that $f$ is differentiable at any $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $x_i\neq 0 \ \forall i$, and the Jacobian at such point can be computed as
\begin{equation}
\partial f_i(x_j) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 &\mbox{if } i\neq j \mbox{ or } x_j < 0,\\
1 &\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
(The Jacobian is thus a diagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are either $0$ or $1$). Clearly, we can partition $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $2^n$ subsets such that $f$ is differentiable on their interiors, and that $Df$ is constant over each subset. These $2^n$ subsets correspond to precisely the $2^n$ orthants of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the $2^n$ Jacobians correspond to the $2^n$ diagonal matrices whose diagonals are from $\{0,1\}^n$. Now, for a point $x$ **on the boundaries of the orthants** (at which $f$ is clearly not differentiable), we can compute $D_Cf(x)$ according to $(*)$ as follows.

Suppose that $x$ lies in the intersection of $k$ orthants $S_1,\dots,S_k$, and that these orthants correspond to the (constant) Jacobians $G_1,\dots,G_k$. For each sequence $x_i$ that converges to $x$ (such that $x_i$ does not meet the boundaries), if $i$ is large enough then obviously $DF(x_i)$ can only take one of the values $G_1,\dots,G_k$, i.e., the sequence $DF(x_i)$ admits cluster points in the set $\{ G_1,\dots,G_k \}$. On the other hand, if we choose the sequence $x_i$ such that all of its elements belong to $S_j$ ($1\le j \le k$), then automatically $DF(x_i)$ converges to $G_j$ because $DF(x_i) = G_j \ \forall i$ (i.e., a constant sequence). We conclude that all the possible limits of in $(*)$ are $\{ G_1,\dots,G_k \}$ and therefore $D_Cf(x) = \mathrm{co} \{ G_1,\dots,G_k \}$.

It remains to determine $\{ G_1,\dots,G_k \}$. Because $x$ is on the boundaries, $x$ must contain at least one zero element. Suppose that $x$ contains exactly $p$ zero elements, then $x$ lies in the intersection of the $k = 2^{p}$ orthants corresponding to the $2^{p}$ Jacobians of the form $G=\mathrm{diag}(g_1,\dots,g_n)$, where
\begin{equation}
g_i = 
\begin{cases} 
0 &\mbox{if }  x_i < 0,\\
1 &\mbox{if }  x_i > 0,\\
\mbox{either } 0 \mbox{ or } 1 &\mbox{if }  x_i = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The convex hull of these $2^{p}$ Jacobians is clearly the set of matrices $\mathrm{diag}(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ such that
\begin{equation}
c_i = 
\begin{cases} 
0 &\mbox{if }  x_i < 0,\\
1 &\mbox{if }  x_i > 0,\\
\mbox{any value in } [0,1] &\mbox{if }  x_i = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the point $x = (0, \color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{-7}, 0)$ lies in the intersection of the $4$ orthants whose Jacobians are $\mathrm{diag}(0, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 0)$, $\mathrm{diag}(0, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 1)$, $\mathrm{diag}(1, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 0)$, and $\mathrm{diag}(1, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 1)$, and thus
\begin{align}
D_Cf(x) &= \mathrm{co} \left\{\mathrm{diag}(0, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 0), \mathrm{diag}(0, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 1), \mathrm{diag}(1, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 0),  \mathrm{diag}(1, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, 1)\right\} \\
&= \left\{\mathrm{diag}(c_1, \color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{0}, c_4): c_1\in [0,1], c_4\in [0,1]\right\}.
\end{align}

**All the above just to arrive at the following simple rule for computing the subdifferential of the $n$-dimensional ReLU function $f$ at a point $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$:**

- Compute $g_i \in \partial \mathrm{ReLU}(x_i)$ (i.e., element-wise subgradient).
- Then $\mathrm{diag}(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ is a Clarke Jacobian of $f$ at $x$.

If the reader find the above derivation hard to understand, I would recommend to apply it to $\mathbb{R}^2$, the idea will become clearer quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Khue. My main question is: what is the subdifferential of $f$?

Comment: @Arthur I have updated the question, showing how to obtain that.

Comment: Thanks @Khue. I think for the $n$-dimensional case, $\partial f$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. So, I guess it should be $\diag$ of the vector you mentioned above. Honestly, what I had in mind was a more compact form or something in terms of convex hull of the gradient at differentiable points. But, I am not sure how I should write it.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry I was in a hurry earlier, you are right that the subgradient should be a matrix. Let me revise the answer in 30 minutes (I'm on mobile now).

Comment: I appreciate it @Khue.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry I was running late. After some quick derivations, I think you are right that the result is $\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{g})$. Subgradients for vector-valued functions is a rather advanced topic that requires generalized notions defined on proper cones. To rigorously prove and confirm the above result it would need me more than a few minutes. It's later here in Europe so let me do that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @Khue. That's right.

Comment: Hi @Arthur. Happy new year! My apologies for the late reply. I was taken by some urgent deadline and then forgot about this question. Today I checked my due TODOs list for 2021 and saw your question on the list :P I have updated my answer, do not hesitate to let me know if your have questions or remarks. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Khue. Happy new year. Thanks for your detailed response. I like it and I think it makes sense. I will go through it more carefully later.

Comment: A recent upvote to this answer reminds me of a shorter and much simpler proof that I wanted to share but then forgot. I’ll post it in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\step#1{\operatorname{\sigma}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let $\sigma$ denote the Heaviside step function (which is the derivative of the ReLu function)
$$\eqalign{
\step{z} = \begin{cases}
\o \quad {\rm if}\;z>0 \\
0 \quad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
Define the vector variables
$$\eqalign{
g &= Ax+b, \qquad
f &= \max(0,g), \qquad
h &= \step{g} \\
}$$
A diagonal matrix $\;H = \Diag{h}\;$ can replace an elementwise/Hadamard product
$$h\odot w = Hw$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of $f$
$$\eqalign{
df &= h\odot dg \\&= h\odot\LR{A\,dx} \\&= H{A\;dx} \\
\grad{f}{x} &= HA \\
}$$
$\ldots$ or the transpose of this, depending on your preferred layout convention.

Comment: Except that the ReLU function is not differentiable so your derivation is not mathematically correct right at the very beginning. The final result is a correct subgradient though, but not all of them.

Comment: $
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\x{\a x}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
$Consider the softplus function $\pi_\a(x)$ 
and its derivative the sigmoid function $\s_\a(x)$
defined by
$$\eqalign{
\pi_\a(x) &= \log\LR{e^{\x}+\o}^{\o/\a} \\
\s_\a(x) &= \LR{e^{-\x}+\o}^{-\o} \\
}$$
These functions are smooth and as $\a$ increases they
become numerically indistinguishable from ${\rm relu}(x)$
and ${\rm step}(x)$. So for all practical purposes
(e.g. Machine Learning), the derivative does exist. The latter functions are used because they are cheaper to compute.