# What is the gradient of plus function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, gradient-descent, operations-research

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ that $f=\frac{1}{2}\|(Ax-b)_+\|^2$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and if $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$: $((x)_+)_i=max\{0,x_i\}$.

I think the gradient of this function is as bellow:
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x)=A^T(Ax-b)_+
\end{equation}
is It true?

Comment: Try it in $n=1$ first. Then $n=2$. Then you can guess the final answer.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3934204/31498

Comment: (If you are only interested in the final results, then look at the bottom of the post.)

Comment: What do you mean by "generalized gradient"?  $A^T(Ax - b)_+$ is simply the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x) = g(h(x))$, where $h(x) = Ax - b$ and
$$
g(u) = \frac12 \| u_+ \|^2 = \frac12\max(u_1,0)^2 + \cdots + \frac12\max(u_m,0)^2.
$$
The function $g$ is certainly differentiable, and
$$
g'(u) = u_+^T.
$$
Also, the derivative of $h$ is $h’(x) = A$.
By the chain rule, $f$ is differentiable and
$$
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = (Ax - b)_+^T A.
$$
If we use the convention that $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector, then
$$
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = A^T(Ax - b)_+.
$$
This confirms that $f$ is a differentiable function and the formula you gave in your question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[matrixcalculus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) can derivate this and similar functions. I wrote OP's function as `1/2*norm2(relu(A*x-b))^2` there and got

function:
$$f = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathrm{relu}(A\cdot x-b)\|_2^{2}$$

gradient:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = A^\top \cdot (\mathrm{relu}(A\cdot x-b)\odot \mathrm{relu}(\mathrm{sign}(A\cdot x-b))).$$
Here $\mathrm{relu}$ is OP's $x \mapsto x_+$, $\odot$ is elementwise multiplication, $\mathrm{sign}$ is elementwise sign.